# i keep getting the error : 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i keep getting the error "'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'" every time i run my program.

i have a form, in that the basic editing has this error. When i click on edit, it redirects me to the code and this exception arise.

Also it says, "System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.Model.get returned null.
"

```
@model MVCApplication.ViewModel.UserViewModel


@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit User";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml"; *here the error comes.
}
```

i expect it to show me the edit screen.

Comment: Can you show us rest of your edit page and your controller action and model

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)